# Shopify Shipping App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, fulfillment

I am trying to create a shopify app which integrates a fulfillment service with my shop. I am trying to fetch shipping addresses from the fulfillment service. For this i have a register a carrier service using API which will accept my callback url from where shopify will fetch the shipping addresses. Now, how can i perform authentication for this step? How only registered users for my fulfillment should able to get shipping rates from this url. Does this url needs to return data in some predefined format? Or Shopify can fetch the rates from the url? Can someone please elaborate more on generating a carrier service in Shopify, authentication, format like these things.

Answer (score 0):

Carrier API calls from Shopify to your App follow the exact same security principle as Webhooks. This means you can authenticate calls from Shopify to your endpoint and not return rates to just anyone. You return JSON with rates. They provide a sample in their Github account. They do not explain how to handle dates very well, you will have to do as I did, experiment and adjust your results as you see how date handling works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked this example https://github.com/Shopify/shipping-fulfillment-app . Not sure if you are pointing to this or anything else. I want to create a carrier service only so i dont need to create a fulfillment service. I hope there are no dependencies. And the request sent by shopify to callback doesn't contain any shop related parameters like shop id. How can i check from which shop the request was sent, which i will use in further processing.

Comment: Carrier service requests are the same as webhooks. They contain the myshopify_domain name, so it is trivial to set the right shop for your rates returned by looking that up in your App db.